The next/Script, `onError` event, how to get the error object
i m using the next/script in my code to load a 3rd party library like so:
<Script
              src="https://js.recurly.com/v4/recurly.js"
              onReady={() => {
                setReady(true)
              }}
              onError={(error) => {
                console.log(error.message) // it returns undefined
                console.log(error) // returns an event
              }}
            />

So, the console.log of the error is an event like so :

In the official documentation (https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/script#onerror) it has this snippet, making obvious that it is an Error object:
import Script from 'next/script'
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <Script
        src="https://example.com/script.js"
        onError={(e: Error) => {
          console.error('Script failed to load', e)
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}

It looks that the callback function into onError does not take the error but the event.  anyone know how we get the actual error ?

Where is that ERORRRRRR in your console coming from?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/error_event looks like one of thses
